# Unable to access calendar information from exchange server

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I'm trying to get calendar information from an exchange server using the exchange api, and I keep running into the following error: " Exchange Server doesn't support the requested version" when I initialise the calendar. The server I'm connecting to is apparently running a hybrid version of exchange.

My code is as follows:

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "pass");

        service.AutodiscoverUrl("url");

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime endDate = startDate.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
        const int NUM_APPTS = 50;

        //error happens on this line
        CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet()); 
        CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);
        cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.Location);
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the version of the ExchangeService object that version you accessing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn741586(v=exchg.150).aspx. If you just want to get it working to start i would suggest

```
new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
```

You can then look at version that the server is running using the

service.ServerInfo.VersionString property

You can also use Autodiscover to determine the version before create the object. eg

```
        AutodiscoverService adAutoDiscoverService = new AutodiscoverService();
        adAutoDiscoverService.Credentials = ncCred;
        adAutoDiscoverService.EnableScpLookup = true;
        adAutoDiscoverService.RedirectionUrlValidationCallback = adAutoDiscoCallBack;
        adAutoDiscoverService.PreAuthenticate = true;
        adAutoDiscoverService.TraceEnabled = true;
        adAutoDiscoverService.KeepAlive = false;
        GetUserSettingsResponse adResponse = adAutoDiscoverService.GetUserSettings("user@domain.com", (new UserSettingName[1] { UserSettingName.EwsSupportedSchemas }))
```